# Advantage of selecting entry where username&password are correct over only selecting username and checking password in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

What is the advantage of selecting a SQL entry where both username and password equal certain values instead of selecting only by username and checking password validity afterwards using e.g PHP?

I know that it is considered correct to use:

(Please don't mind SQL injectability and missing hashing in this pseudo code)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='Manfred' AND password='securepass'
```

instead of using

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='Manfred'
```

and checking

```
if ($row['password'] == "securepass") {
    //authenticated
}
```

Both ways worked for me as expected in a test environment, however I am wondering if I am missing a considerable security reason.

Comment: Because, it's always good practice to use more than one field where there stands to be collisions. Plus, you don't want to let a user login / be verified by just their email/username would you? I mean what if someone "guesses" a username? Think about that.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if I'm getting your answer correctly. The user is only authenticated after the password was checked with the `if` in PHP right?

Comment: Right and using double verification. Your *"instead of"* isn't recommended, since like I said, if someone guesses for an existing record/email/username and succeeds, they'd of had access to that person's record, "they" being "hackers/sniffers". (welcome).

Comment: But how can they (hackers/sniffers) get access to the person's record when I do not supply them with any information before the entered password is the correct one?

Comment: *Heh,* you'd be surprised, *really*.

Comment: Please, enlighten me :-)

Comment: Sorry, but this is way too long a subject to talk about.

Comment: Okay, are there any keywords that I might use for googeling the problem?

Comment: Sure: "how can a hacker guess a username". You've got a lot of reading to do, enjoy. Have a safe and happy Xmas.

Comment: I usually pass the hash as part of the query, but it makes no difference at all.

Answer (score 3):

The first approach is simpler, but not more "correct" than the second. It will depend on the system requirements.

Considering the following requirements:
If your project has audit requirement that 
1) must lock down an account if password fails more than X times; (1st approach will require at least one update statement regardless whether account exists)
2) must audit log when an account failed login (if 1st approach, you will even log those non-exist accounts)

Some may argue that in the 1st approach, the application layer doesn't touch the password stored, but it doesn't mean the second way not secure. If the application layer cannot be trusted, the system has a bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using compare statement on php-side allows you to apply cryptographic algorithms + it's not secure to store passwords as a raw value in DB. Usually hashes/crypto-hashes are stored in DB, and when you get pair $user+$pass you get user from DB and check matching of that hash with result of that algorithm applied to $pass.

Comment: I know, but how does that answer my question?
What is the advantage of using only a mysql query?

Comment: Ok, if you know about http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php secure mechanics and you familiar with mysql-injections. So the difference is in required algorithms. Simple variant: sometime we need to get User object and match it's password independently -> in this case we may specify different messages for incorrect user and for incorrect user+pass. More complicated variant: we are strict by system/framework we are working on...

Comment: E.g. currently working with symfony, it's FOSUserBundle works with 2 fields: salt + password, and you have a [algorythm] specified in settings. So getting pair of original user+pass you need to:
- retrieve user by `username`/`email` (entity);
- get it's `salt` + apply [algotythm] to `salt`+`raw pass` => then you get the value from `password` field;
- and only after that you'll be able to compare `algotythm(salt+raw_pass)` with `password` field

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you are still not answering my question. I am familiar with hashing and cryptograhpy. My question is a different, please have a look at it again.